# How to launch .exe file in uwp app using fulltrustlauncher?

Tags: uwp, launch, desktop-bridge

for now, i need to execute a .exe file in my uwp app. I know a solution is using fulltrustlauncher, but i have searched for many times for this solution, but my programming level seem too low, so It is very difficult for me to understand their explaination (for example: [Running an EXE from C# using UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900471/running-an-exe-from-c-sharp-using-uwp)
). So, how do you have a simple sample code for this solution? can you sharing? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I can launch my .exe file in my UWP Application. I will describe my workaround step by step like this:
1. Create your executable .exe file (for example console application) 
2. copy .exe file to your UWP Application start up folder (for example: Assets folder)
3. In UWP App Solution Explorer, add reference to "Windows Desktop Extensions For The UWP v10.0.14393.0"(or higher) under "References > Universal Windows > Extensions".
4. In UWP App Solution Explorer, open Package.appxmanifest xml file (right click on Package.appxmanifest file --> view code). add these namespace

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
```

to **Package** tag. And then, add this extension:

```
<Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\YourExecutableFileName.exe" />
</Extensions>
```

under **Application** tag. And then, add this code:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
```

into your **Capabilities** tag. this step mean: talk to compiler to know that it shuld trust your .exe file in the **Assets\YourExecutableFileName.exe** location. 
5. In your UWP Application whenever you want to launch the .exe file, you need to execute this code:

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

reference:[Great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900471/running-an-exe-from-c-sharp-using-uwp)

Comment: how can I add multiple `<desktop:extension>` with  `Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" `in case I need to execute individual exe  for appropriate function and how to identify each of them to call in code. When I try to add more than one `<desktop:extention>` with `category = fullTrestProcess` I get this error : `The Extension element with Category attribute value "windows.fullTrustProcess" must only be declared once`. Could you help me, thanks.

Comment: @neo, at the moment I don't know how to run multiple win 32 apps, but if you need execute multi-functions, you can pass parameters to your win 32 app. see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978066/how-to-launch-exe-app-with-parameter-uwp

Comment: Does the .exe file that will be running have limitations? E.g. accessing User32.dll? Can it be run as administrator?

Comment: When I add rescap-capability part into the <capabilities> section, I get this weird error. https://ibb.co/gTGz5Rc Error reads as "The element 'Capabilitis' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace '.../restrictedcapabilities'  " . Could you post Package.appxmanifest file content if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The EXE needs to be included in the appx package, and declared in the appxmanifest. Also make sure you declare the 'runFullTrust' capability in the appxmanifest. That's all you need. If that doesn't help, please ask a more detailed question, so we understand what exactly doesn't work for you.

MSDN documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher

GitHub samples that use this feature:

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample_C%2B%2B

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Office%20Interop

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Systray