# How to launch .exe app with parameter uwp

Tags: uwp, exe, launch, desktop-bridge

I know we can use [LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher#Windows_ApplicationModel_FullTrustProcessLauncher_LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync_System_String_) method 
and

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="fulltrustprocess.exe"> 
  <desktop:FullTrustProcess> 
    <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/Sync"/> 
    <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters="/Other"/> 
  </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
```

to launch and send parameter to win32 app. But my big question is: How to receive that parameter in my win32 app (in my case win32 app is my Console Application). Does anyone has any help. thank you.

**Update for Stefan answer** 
in win32 app always have **Main(string[] args)**, so if another app launch our win32 .exe with parameter (for example: "my parameter" string), **args** string array will contains that "my parameter" string, I sure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are delivered as arguments in the Main() function of your Win32 process.

Comment: accepted as answer because it focus on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Better option is to use App Services.

An app service can allow you to communicate to and fro between two applications. Fortunately there exists a UWP extension for desktop application which can help you consume app service in your win32 project. Here are the steps.

**1. Install UwpDesktop in your Win32 app**

```
Install-Package UwpDesktop
```

**2. Create an App Service endpoint in your Win32 app**

```
    private async void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppServiceConnection connection = new AppServiceConnection();
        connection.AppServiceName = "CommunicationService";
        connection.PackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
        var result = await connection.OpenAsync();
        if (result == AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
        {
            ValueSet valueSet = new ValueSet();
            valueSet.Add("name", txtName.Text);

            var response = await connection.SendMessageAsync(valueSet);
            if (response.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Success)
            {
                string responseMessage = response.Message["response"].ToString();
                if (responseMessage == "success")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If your .exe file is part of the UWP project, your `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName` should redirect to the UWP's PFN.

**3. Create the other side of the channel in UWP app**

Now create a basic app service in your UWP app

```
AppServiceConnection connection = new AppServiceConnection();
connection.AppServiceName = "CommunicationService";
connection.PackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
var result = await connection.OpenAsync();
```

**4. Handle connection request**

Last, you need to handle incoming connection in `Connection_RequestReceived`

```
private async void Connection_RequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
    string name = args.Request.Message["name"].ToString();
    Result.Text = $"Hello {name}";
    ValueSet valueSet = new ValueSet();
    valueSet.Add("response", "success");
    await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(valueSet);
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Though we are only returning `valueSet` with only one item, you can include other items like specific instructions or parameters in the `valueSet`. These will be available to you as result at Win32 side.

This is a very simple example scaled down from official MSDN blog post by centennial team found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/12/19/desktop-bridge-the-migrate-phase-invoking-a-win32-process-from-a-uwp-app/

To make it more robust you can make sure you create the app service connection at UWP end only once your Win32 application is up by using `AppServiceTriggerDetails` as in the blog post

You will also need to declare app service in **Package.appxmanifest** file

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
    <uap:AppService Name="CommunicationService" />
  </uap:Extension>
  <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Migrate.WindowsForms.exe" />
</Extensions>
```

You can find the sample from the blog post here:

https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridge/tree/master/6.%20Migrate

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: I think your new approach may be better than launching exe file approach, but your answer doesn't focus on above question. thanks.