# How to pass data between launches of AHK executable from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, autohotkey

I want to launch my AHK script like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911755/how-to-launch-exe-file-in-uwp-app-using-fulltrustlauncher). I will need to do two different things, A and B. I can either put them in one script, or two separate scripts. But B needs some data from A, which is where my problem lies.

- Solution one: Put A and B into one script, and somehow notify it when it's time for part B, but without restarting it. But how?
- Solution two: Put them into separate scripts, and somehow pass the values between them. But again, how? The value does not fit into the exit code, and I also don't know how to get the exit code and now to launch multiple executables from and UWP app.

Comment: Have you considered having the first script write to a text file and then having the next script read from that file?  [Write](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm) and [Read](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileReadLine.htm) are not too difficult to implement.

Comment: AHK can also do `RegWrite` and `RegRead` as well as `IniWrite` and `IniRead` to pass info. With cloud sync and using `A_ComputerName` and/or `A_UserName` in the ini file name, you can pass pc- or user-specific info between AHK scripts.