# How to launch exe file in uwp project?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm creating gui app in uwp for a cli programm. I wanted to run exe file in uwp project but I found out that Start.Process is not possible in uwp. I did some research and thought that's the best answer: [How to launch .exe file in uwp app using fulltrustlauncher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911755/how-to-launch-exe-file-in-uwp-app-using-fulltrustlauncher).

I followed the instructions and everything seemed to be fine (except one warning by `<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />` fragment, but that's a long one, so I'll paste it at the end). I tried to compiled it and it worked(!), but when I clicked on a button, which should trigger the event:

```
private async void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
}
```

I got an error:

The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.

Is there some solution for this?

That warning I mentioned:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'. List of possible elements expected: 'CapabilityChoice' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/7' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http*//schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2' as well as 'CustomCapabilityChoice' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'CustomCapability' in namespace 'http*://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4' as well as 'Dev....    ez-renamer-gui  C:\Users\sienk\Documents\github\ez-renamer-gui\ez-renamer-gui\Package.appxmanifest  52

I added "*" after https, because I can't add more than 8 links.

Comment: "Is there some solution for this?", yes, fix your fulltrust declaration in the manifest, the one that is giving you a warning.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, please share a sample project with onedrive, I will the test.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Here's the link: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsrmG1yLd4892wx_aFMKHbyFRnJ7. I shared the whole project.