# Running two different exes from UWP

Tags: uwp

I managed to run a .exe file at startup using the answer given here:
[Running an EXE from C# using UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900471/running-an-exe-from-c-sharp-using-uwp)

However, I need to run another executable when my UWP app is closed. Does anybody know how to do this? Is there a way to link two different exes to the FullTrustLauncher? Or maybe there is a way to parameterize the usage of this FullTrustLauncher? I know the launch async function can be parameterized, but I have no idea what there parameters are for. So, an example would be nice.

Cheers!

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008948/how-to-launch-a-full-trust-desktop-bridge-app-from-uwp-with-arbitrary-paramete

Answer (score 0):

That parameter cannot be used to customize things like what you think. Also UWP apps lifecycle has already wrote something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-close):
“There is not an event to indicate that the user closed the app.”

So if you really need to do something like this, maybe:
1. You can detect the user's close "X", see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview
2. Like Ipsit Gaur's link showed, follow Stefan's advice to create extra exe to read command strings.

However in general your request is not a good request. Or even it will leads a bad user experience in my mind.